# React crashes on array.map even though the map loop isn't being entered

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The component `ProductCategoriesPicker` is accepting an array of categories as `categoriesState`, which is currently just an empty array `[]`

Here's the component:

```
import React from 'react'

const ProductCategoriesPicker = ({ categoriesState, onCheck }) =>  (
   <div className="product-categories-picker">
       <h5> MY product categories </h5>
       <ul>
           categoriesState.map( (cat, idx)  =>  
               <li>
                   <label>
                       <input 
                           type="checkbox"
                           checked={cat.checked}
                           onChange={onCheck}
                       />
                       {cat.name}
                   </label>
               </li>
           )   
       </ul>
   </div>

)

export default ProductCategoriesPicker
```

But no matter how I set it up, I get a crash with error message `cat is not defined`

First of all, shouldn't map not even enter the loop on an empty array? I've tried several measures to guard against this regardless, and none of them stop the error message:

```
categoriesState && cateogoriesState.map ... // same error
categoriesState.length > 0 && categoriesState.map ... // same error
```

And if I try to get a console.log on the cat, nothing at all shows up (not even `undefined`, which makes me think that indeed, this loop is not being entered.

```
categoriesState.map( (cat, idx) => console.log(cat) &&
```

This is complete looney toons -- why does the app crash on this error!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it's a translation error to SO, but it looks like you have some syntax errors. I'm fairly sure you need to have your `categoriesState.map()` inside `{}` and also to implicitly return the `<li>` JSX, it needs to be wrapped in `()`:

```
<ul>
  {categoriesState.map((cat, idx) => (
    <li>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" checked={cat.checked} onChange={onCheck} />
        {cat.name}
      </label>
    </li>
  ))}
</ul>
```

EDIT: As pointed out in comments, the parentheses are not required for implicit return

Comment: Ahhh wow I need more coffee... or less. Thanks, that was indeed the problem. You can implicit return without the parens though for the record.

Comment: needing to add the curly braces was my thought too.  parentheses around JSX isn't necessary, since it will transpile to `(cat, idx) => React.createElement('li', ...)` which is syntactically valid.

Comment: ah okay my bad, thanks guys; i use prettier and it adds them there